# How to transition element when changing its relative top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In jquery I change an elements position (which has relative positioning) with `$(elem).css("top",x);`.
But how can I do this and animate or transition it, so it moves to the new location fast but not instantly.

Thanks.

Comment: If you create a fiddle of your current situation you'll get a decent answer quicker

Comment: Try searching the jQuery API docs for "animate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways :

1 . you can use Jquery `animate()` like this :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5pvwW/

learn more about Jquery `animate()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) .

2 . also can use css `transition` like this :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/eeBDh/

learn more about `transition` in this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) .